# Обратиться к гетеру в модели

Tags: java, android, get

Хочу обратиться к get'еру во вложенной модели.

Поясню, в моём фрагменте есть:

`List<Control> controlList = new ArrayList<>();`

А уже в модели `Control` находится:

```
private List<ImageUpload> imageUploads = new ArrayList<>();
```

И следовательно в `ImageUpload` у меня параметр

```
private String url;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
```

Пробую получить url во фрагменте следующим образом:

```
controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().getUrl();
```

но `getUrl` выделяет красным...( хотя по идее не должен.
Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку.

Model `ImageUploads`

```
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("output_metadata")
@Expose
private OutputMetadata outputMetadata;
@SerializedName("handler")
@Expose
private Integer handler;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
private List<VideoUpload> videoUploads = new ArrayList<>();
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
```

Comment: А какую позицию во вложенном списке вам надо получить? или весь вложенный список?

Comment: @pavlofff извините, не совсем понял вопрос. Позицию элемента в списке - у каждого элемента своя ссылка её и нужно получить.

Comment: У вас в коллекцию `controlList` вложена еще одна коллекция (`imageUploads`), там несколько элементов (ссылок) - какая из них вам нужна (или все)?

Comment: @pavlofff только getUrl

Comment: У вас несколько элементов в списке imageUploads .. несколько, вы пытаетесь обращаться, как будто там не список, а одна переменная, а у вас список в списке

Comment: @pavlofff я понимаю, но к примеру при работе с картинкой, мне достаточно было написать controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(0,imageUpload);
а тут просто хочу сохранять ссылки

Comment: Методом get() вы можете их получить, а не сохранить - это обратное действие

Comment: @pavlofff значит сначала мне нужно просэтить url, а потом получить, правильно я понимаю?

Answer (score 4):

У вас же `getImageUploads()` возвращает список. Должно быть как-то так:

```
controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(imagePosition).getUrl();
```

Comment: imagePosition в роли чего тут вообще выступает?
обновил вопрос (добавил модель), взгляните пожалуйста

Comment: @Inkognito imagePosition тут выступает в роли позиции элемента во вложенном списке, того, чего я от вас не могу добиться никак, какая позиция вам там нужна

Comment: @pavlofff позиция всех добавленных элементов, нет никакой конкретной.

Comment: @pavlofff допустим я получил данные url, как мне потом добавить его?
по примеру того как я добавлял картинку controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(0,imageUpload);